# Reopen review weekly count showing wrong value

Tags: bug, review-stats

Is this a bug with the count displayed against the "week" (or) is it a misunderstanding on my part of how it works?

The cap for reopen review count per day is 20 (for a normal user, not sure about moderators). So the max count that one can reach in a week is 140. But my weekly count is shown as 143.

[image]

I guess the votes cast for the last 7 days + today is being used for the calculation.

**EDIT:** This seems to be the same for the other items in the review section also.